# Detect MIDI connection events

Tags: javascript, node.js, midi

I want to be able to support local and remote MIDI streaming mode to web clients.
While the former can easily be done:

```js
navigator.requestMIDIAccess().then(function(access) {
  const inputs = access.inputs.values()
  for (const input of inputs) {
    if (input.name === "Roland Digital Piano MIDI 1") {
      input.onmidimessage = message => {
        // handle events ...
      }
    }
  }
  access.onstatechange = function(e) {
    // handle dis/re-connection ...
  }
})
```

I can't find a good cross-platform library that does the same (tried `rtmidi`-based ones, but it doesn't provide any information about a disconnected state).

Is there a way in js, python or any other language to do the same?

---

Comment: You need some sort of server if you're going to relay this to a browser.  Is your question how to access MIDI from Node.js?  Or just how to connect two web-based clients together?

Comment: @Brad I already have a Node.js-(and a python-) working version that streams it to the frontend with WebSockets. I just can't detect a disconnection/reconnection, so every time I turn my piano off and on again it stops working and there's no way to recover. I was wondering if the same functionality of WebMIDI (specifically onstatechange) is out there for Node.js / python

Comment: That's dependent on what API you're using in either, and is probably platform dependent as well.  For what it's worth, I've found that the `statechange` even in-browser isn't all that reliable either.  (At least, not in Chrome.)  It works about 85% of the time, and the rest of the time something gets stuck.  I haven't been able to narrow down whether the issue is with Chrome, Windows, the USB MIDI driver, or what.  Point being... you'll probably have to resort to polling anyway.